# How do I read task parameters in a Databricks Job?

Tags: databricks

The job is running a Python file, not a notebook. All the examples I can find online use the notebook utility which Databricks says is unreliable inside of executors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out - when calling from the **Jobs API**, you have to include

`"spark_python_task":{"python_file":"dbfs:/FileStore/my_script.py", "parameters": ["param1", "param2"]}`

and when calling from the **UI** (run with new paramaters) you need to include

`{"spark_python_task": ["param1","param2"]}`

Each time, for reading you read with `sys.argv`. (`sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` in this example).

Comment: do you know why it has to be included? I was following this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/dbx#create-minimal-project where they don't include param1 and param2 but my job kept failing until I found this post~